# Angular HTML Expressions

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular js and have now a question where I couldn't find the right answer yet.

in the template HTML, you can use expressions to show the scope variables or call scope functions. But I see all the time different versions of it.

`{{name}}` shows the variable and binds it

`{{::name}}` the same thing but without binding

`userdirective="{{::key}}"` But what is the difference here?

`ng-if="::field.sortable"` With ng-if they are not using {{ but with there userdirective they do?

`userdirective="{condition:isActive(route.name),mdColors:{color:'primary'}}"` And then there is the last one with just one {. Thats when you create an object.right?

Maybe someone can help me to understand all of it.
Thank you very much for your time. Pat

Comment: I think this article could be a good starting point on explaining these: http://moduscreate.com/the-magic-of-angular-js-two-way-binding/

Comment: Official documentation for AngularJs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{name}}` as you say is two-way data-binding

`{{::name}}` one way databinding

`userdirective="{{::key}}"` is the interesting case. This statement uses one-way binding into the userdirective ... which means after the `$digest` it just says `userdirective="someValue"`

So the userdirective gets that value as a plain value. Now I would have to test it but in the `scope`part of the directiive it should say `@` so it gets read as a string and not as a expression.

The last one is simply as any JSON you build

```
{ name: value?true:false }
```

setting value according to conditions that angular evaluates, with a bit of magic involved :D

hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the explanation. but i still have one question: 
there is for example `userdirective="{{test}}"` but i see also something like `ng-if="test"`. does that mean that i actually dont need the `{{` to pass a variable or object to a directive?

Comment: sorry for the late answer... the answer is yes. ... ng-if expects a expressions in this case `test` ...if `test` true ...you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

`{{ anything here}}` - That is angular expression interpolation. [Angular interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) - here you can find more about that. Basically idea that it interpolate anything you will put inside those brackets. So if you will put expression with some calculations or just variables related to current scope it will convert all variables to their values and apply calculations.

For instance: `{{scopevar1 + scopevar2}}` in case this variables has some values, let it be `1` and `2`, as result we will see `3`.

`::`  - This mean `one time binding`. For instance `{{::scopevar1}}` it will be interpolated once and will not check for changes of `scopevar1`, always stay as first value. Even if `scopevar1` will change every second, the value in template will be the same. [Angular Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) - here you can find some live examples and more information.

`userdirective="{{::key}}"` - This case is nothing more then assigning dynamic value to your directive. `UserDirective` expectes to get a simple value, but we have it inside our `scope`, so we need to say: Hey, angular please interpolate scope variable - `key`, but only once, so my directive will get value, and will not looking for updates of `key`. And angular does it with pleasure!

`userdirective="{condition:isActive(route.name),mdColors:{color:'primary'}}"`
 The last case is when your directive expects to get some kind of specific JSON. And we don't want to build it inside of controller. It is sometimes easier to do such things in the tempalte. So we put specific object with two properties: `condition, mdColors`. And saying that first property assigned to result of function, and second one is simple object `{color:'primary'}`.

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

{{var}} is a two way binding expression and {{::var}} is a one-way binding expression.  expression with :: will not change once set, it is a candidate for one-time binding.
go through : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression for better examples on these

Answer (score 0):

`{{name}}` is the regular case you will find. You basically print the variable `name` and update it once it changes.

`{{::name}}` is the same but your value will not receive updates once it stabilises.

So in the first case, your template updates once `name` is changed. In the latter, it isn't.

`userdirective="{{::key}}"` is a `one-way one-time binding`. Leave the `::` out and your directive receives updates if key changes. However, if the directive changes key, it will not update the parent.

`ng-if="::field.sortable"` is a two-way binding. The changes go both ways. In this case, field.sortable is watched by the directive.

`userdirective="{condition:isActive(route.name),mdColors:{color:'primary'}}"` is used when you want to build adhoc-objects. A popular case is `ng-class` as well. You may build this object in the controller as well as you should not put too much logic in your template.

In any case, it is advisable to read the excellent docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide